# Шаблон MVVM и GWT

Tags: java, mvvm, gwt, шаблоны-проектирования

Может кто слышал об реализации шаблона MVVM в GWT? Я говорю о технологии подобной WPF в C#.

Comment: А в чём отличие от MVP? И какая такая особая поддержка требуется для этого паттерна от GWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А, всё, я понял в чём суть. Для похожих целей в GWT используется UiBinder. Копайте в его направлении.

Comment: По моему мнению, UiBinder еще сыроват. Может есть альтернатива?

Comment: Сыроват? В проекте, над которым я работаю, он используется довольно активно и обычно всё прекрасно.

Comment: Учту :)

Comment: Не нашел ничего лучше.